# How can I convert this date Regex from 'dd/mm/yyyy' to 'dd-mm-yyyy'?

Tags: jquery, regex

Given the regex:

```
(/^\d\d?\/\d\d?\/\d\d\d\d$/)
```

Which means `"Please enter a date in the format dd/mm/yyyy."`

How can I swap the slashes with dashes so it's on the format `dd-mm-yyyy`?

Comment: ... Change `\/` to `-`?

Comment: That worked. Thankyou, I am new with reg-expressions.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Comment: jquery for validation dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
/^\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4}$/
```

You can also try your regex live on http://www.phpliveregex.com/ or http://regex101.com/

Answer (score 2):

Use this regex instead:

```
/^\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4}$/
```

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/cP0gF6/1)!

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace the forward slashes with dashes:

```
(/^\d\d?-\d\d?-\d\d\d\d$/)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is modified from [here](http://regex101.com/r/tH1cV7/1):

`^(0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8]|29(?=-\d\d-(?!1[01345789]00|2[1235679]00)\d\d(?:[02468][048]|[13579][26]))|30(?!-02)|31(?=-0[13578]|-1[02]))-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-([12]\d{3})$`

Why do you want all of that?  Because it handles valid dates and leap years, etc.

Try it out [here](http://regex101.com/r/cY8eW0/1)

---

```
20-02-2013 - valid
29-02-1700 - not valid
29-02-1600 - valid
29-02-1604 - valid
29-02-2001 - not valid
31-01-2000 - valid
30-02-2000 - not valid
29-02-2004 - valid
31-02-2000 - not valid
31-12-2000 - valid
31-06-2000 - not valid
15-02-2000 - valid
29-02-2002 - not valid
29-02-2004 - valid
29-02-1800 - not valid
29-02-2000 - valid
29-02-1900 - not valid
28-02-2000 - valid
```

---

In no way did I come up with this by myself in 16 minutes (time from post of question to post of my answer). As mentioned, I modified one that was already created - the author of which is far better than I am in RegEx